# How to invert custom brush in GIMP

Tags: gimp, brush

Is it possible to invert a custom brush?
I am not talking about angle/rotation/horizontally but what part of the brush is drawn on the canvas.
I want to invert it in a way so the area which normally does not apply color will apply color.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: Paint black into a originally white layer mask. Have a new layer with white layer mask and the layer itself filled partially or fully with the new color. The layer must have alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

- `Windows>Dockable dialogs>Brushes`
- Right-click the brush, and `Open brush as image` (image should be grayscale)
- `Color>Invert`

Two ways to use the brush:

- One-time use:

  - `Select>Select All`
  - `Edit>Copy`
  - Use the `clipboard` brush (first in list)
- Long-term use:

  - `File>Export` as .GBR, in one of the directories listed by `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Brushes` (the one you can write into).